# On loading vich uploader image on Twig template showing File not uploadable exception

Tags: symfony, twig, vichuploaderbundle

I´m facing a challenge when trying to show a image that was uploaded using vich uploader on twig template. An error message is going like this:

```
   <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(manchete.arquivoDaImagem, 'arquivoDaImagem') }}">
```

But it´s throwing an error message like this:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File" is not uploadable.
>   If you use annotations to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably
>   just forgot to add `@Vich\Uploadable` on top of your entity. If you
>   don't use annotations, check that the configuration files are in the
>   right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the
>   issue.").

My Manchete entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MancheteRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Manchete { ...
```

The file attribute is like this:

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="manchete_images", fileNameProperty="caminhoDaImagem")
 * @var File
 */
private $arquivoDaImagem;
```

Any idea what´s happening here?

Comment: Do you have `use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;` at the top of your class?

Comment: hey @fyrye already solved thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I found I was passing:

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(manchete.arquivoDaImagem, 'arquivoDaImagem') }}">
```

The correct approach is to pass:

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(manchete, 'arquivoDaImagem') }}">
```

now it works.